Rails 6 Heroku asset compilation
We're running a Rails 6.1 app on Heroku using Sprockets. For the longest time we've had config.assets.compile = true on our staging and production environments, but Heroku complains and suggests that be set to false.
There isn't much detail in this documentation however. I've tried setting this to false, and deploy, and assets seem to compile as expected, or at least there are no errors (see output below). But when I hit the server, assets are not present. I am trying to understand what is the recommended flow here. Are we missing a step? I see that compiling assets locally first is a potential option, but would prefer to avoid that if there's a way. But if that is the best option does anyone have suggestions on a sane flow for this?
Like, compile assets locally, deploy, delete local assets?
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile                                                                                                                
remote:        yarn install v1.22.19
remote:        warning package.json: No license field
remote:        info No lockfile found.                          
remote:        warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
remote:        warning No license field                                       
remote:        [1/5] Validating package.json...            
remote:        warning No license field                                                                                                                       
remote:        [2/5] Resolving packages...                                                                                                                    
remote:        [3/5] Fetching packages...                                     
remote:        [4/5] Linking dependencies...                    
remote:        [5/5] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 0.05s.                
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (3.84s)    
remote:        Cleaning assets                             
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean     
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration


precompiling assets on deploy is the way to do this. If it's not working then you might want to do some logging. Rails.application.config.assets.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
